# Вызвать из Javascript метод python-а

Tags: python, javascript, qt

Нужно из `javascript` функции вызвать метод класса.
Можете подсказать как это делается? Небольшого примера мне хватит
ЯП: `python`
Используется: `PyQt`

[QtWebKit-специфика при разработке мобильных HTML5-приложений](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133690/) есть как это делается на C++. Но я не могу разобраться как в Питон перевести.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. При чём здесь JavaScript?

Comment: У Qt есть модуль Webkit. Можно на html-страницу (загруженную, созданную или т.п.) добавлять свой js-код. И из него можно вызывать методы

Comment: Интересно нашел ли автор ответ, сам задумался.

Comment: Увы, но нет.

Answer (score 2):

Буду слоупоком, но может кому то понадобиться. Нашел ответ, несколько костыльный, но рабочий [Ways to communicate from an embedded WebKit widget to the controlling Python program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97430/connect-webkit-webview-form-to-a-python-callback/97682#97682).

В `javascript` меняем `document.title` а потом ловим в `python`, например в GTK

```
web = WebKit.WebView()
web.get_title()
```

В Qt можно тоже самое, так же пишут что там уже предусмотрен сей момент: [Calling Python from JavaScript in PyQt's QWebkit](http://pysnippet.blogspot.ru/2010/01/calling-python-from-javascript-in-pyqts.html)

Answer (score 0):

[PyV8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/)

Comment: Спасибо. Но все же не то. У PyQt это своими силами можно